# Preload react component on Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im trying to build a nextjs project with an unity game, there are some pages (/welcome page , /tutorial page and /information page) that the user will go before going to the game, so I want to preload the game component and have it ready when the user goes to the game page (/game).

I tried to add the game with a display none to the nextjs layout but every time I navigate to another page the game gets reloaded.

I was think is to have a SPA where I will show all the pages on the same url, but I just want to double check there is a another way to achieve this.